# Which way of referencing S3 files is better / faster?

Tags: performance, amazon-s3, dns, domain-name

Is this method of addressing S3 files better / more reliable / faster?

```
http://abcinfo.s3.amazonaws.com/something.doc
```

or this way:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/abcinfo/something.doc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fascinating discovery!

```
http://abcinfo.s3.amazonaws.com/something.doc
```

Is CONSISTENTLY slower than the other reference mechanism!

File used: Length: 3716075 (3.5M) [video/mp4]

```
wget http://myfolder.s3.amazonaws.com/mytestfile.mp4
7.0s
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/myfolder/mytestfile.mp4
2.2s
wget http://myfolder.s3.amazonaws.com/mytestfile.mp4
9.7s
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/myfolder/mytestfile.mp4
2.2s
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/myfolder/mytestfile.mp4
2.1s
wget http://myfolder.s3.amazonaws.com/mytestfile.mp4
9.9s
wget http://myfolder.s3.amazonaws.com/mytestfile.mp4
9.2s
```

Average time taken in http://myfolder mechanism:

```
8.95 seconds
```

Average time taken in /myfolder/ mechanism:

```
2.166666667 seconds
```

ie, the former is at least FOUR times as slower!